# ready function in Jquery not giving output

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

HTML part of code

```
 <section>
 <textarea class= "text" placeholder="type something"> </textarea> </br> </br>
    <button id= "append"> Append </button>
    <button id= "prepand"> Prepand </button>
    <button id= "replace"> Replace </button>
</section>
```

JQuery part of code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#append','#prepand','#replace').on('click', function(e){

           var e1 = $(e.currentTarget);
           var action = e1.attr('id');

           if (action == "prepand"){
             console.log("Prepanding");
           }
           else if (action == "append") {
             console.log("Appending");
           }
           else if(action == "replace"){
             console.log("Replacing");
           }});

           });
```

I wanted to see the output of buttons whether they are working or not but there is not output on console. Please help

Comment: What do you think this does `$('#append','#prepand','#replace')`?  I suspect you meant `$('#append,#prepand,#replace')`  (note a single string)

Comment: Off topic: looks like you've misspelt "prepend" but could be a different language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For use all three ID just write one quote for all.

Updated code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){     

    $('#append,#prepand,#replace').on('click', function(e){ 

           var e1 = $(e.currentTarget);
           var action = e1.attr('id');

           if (action == "prepand"){
             console.log("Prepanding");
           }
           else if (action == "append") {
             console.log("Appending");
           }
           else if(action == "replace"){
             console.log("Replacing");
           }
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<textarea class= "text" placeholder="type something"> </textarea> </br> </br>
    <button id= "append"> Append </button>
    <button id= "prepand"> Prepand </button>
    <button id= "replace"> Replace </button>
</section>                                                              
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <section>
```

Comment: _For use all three ID just write one quote for all._ ..

Comment: I edited when you write the comment, nice timing ;)

Comment: Thanks for you improve.